# MVC3 default route to area doesn't search for view inside area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I set the default route object to a controller ("Beheer") inside an area (also called "Beheer").

Like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Beheer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

It can find that controller and the action fine inside the Area, but it can not find the view because it only looks in these locations:

```
~/Views/Beheer/Index.aspx
~/Views/Beheer/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Beheer/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Beheer/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

While it should be looking in this location:

```
~/Beheer/Views/Beheer/Index.aspx
```

How can I make it search for the view there?

I already tried:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { area = "Beheer", controller = "Beheer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And I tried this (with namespaces):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Beheer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "Areas.Beheer" }
    );
```

But nothing changes. It enters the correct action in the correct controller but can't find the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your route in the area registration. BeheerAreaRegistration has a property that sets the area name.

```
 
    public class BeheerAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
       public override string AreaName
       {
         get
         {
           return "Beheer";
         }
        }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
       context.MapRoute( "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Beheer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults);
    }
```

Comment: This is already present in the BeheerAreaRegistration. Should I change something here?

Comment: if your route is set in the area registration and your view is in Areas/Beheer/Views/Beheer/ it should work

Comment: Thank you. My URL in the MapRoute method was written differently. Like this `"Beheer/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`. This was done by default. I'll have to check if everything else still works. One thing that changes is the URL if I go to the page directly. I wanted it to be `~/beheer/{method}` but now it is `~/{method}`. How can I get that URL back?

Comment: I also had to keep the old route in the AreaRegistration to keep the old URL's working. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found I needed to fully qualify the namespaces and I has issues with it finding the right view until I killed the IIS process, some sort of odd caching or something maybe.

```
new[] { "Areas.Beheer" }
```

might become

```
new[] {"myApp.Areas.Beheer.Controllers"}
```

maybe your problem is similar to mine - maybe not.